# How to optimize flutter sdk version and other configurations?

Tags: flutter, dart, version-control

When I download any project that has different sdk version,everytime I have some troubles until running the project.Manually I change some data...It is so painfull to do it.Is there any way that automaticly optimizes flutter sdk version ?By doing it I can easyly build any flutter project.[image: as you see I got an error]

Answer (score -1):

Your problem as I saw in the image it's about an Indentation error which unfortunately you must fix it because pubspec.yaml use it.
To big understand Indentation Which is a different style of syntax in file formats try this with [Python Indentation](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_indentation.asp).